# Leer un JSON anidado con Gson usando varias clases ¿Por qué recibo «null object reference»?

Tags: java, android, gson

Estoy intentado leer un JSON anidado con la ayuda de la librería `Gson`.

El JSON lo recibo bien, no tiene error, lo he validado, y tiene esta estructura:

```
{
    "breviario": {
        "metaLiturgia": {
                "fecha"  : "Viernes 02 de noviembre del 2018",
                "tiempo" : "PROPIO DE LOS SANTOS",
                "semana"   : "",
                "mensaje": "",
                "salterio": "",
                "color":0,
                "meta": ""
        },
        "santo": {
                "nombre": "Conmemoración de todos los Fieles Difuntos",
                "vida": "La santa Madre Iglesia, después de su solicitud para celebrar con las debidas alabanzas la dicha de todos sus hijos bienaventurados en el cielo, se interesa ante el Señor en favor de las almas de cuantos nos precedieron con el signo de la fe y duermen en la esperanza de la resurrección, y por todos los difuntos desde el principio del mundo, cuya fe solo Dios conoce, para que, purificados de toda mancha de pecado y asociados a los ciudadanos celestes, puedan gozar de la visión de la felicidad eterna. <br />Martirologio Romano"
        },

        "oficio": {
            "invitatorio": {
                "antifona": "Al Señor, rey de los que viven, venid, adorémosle.",
                "texto": "Venid, aclamemos al Señor,~demos vítores a la Roca que nos salva;~entremos a su presencia dándole gracias,~aclamándolo con cantos.§Porque el Señor es un Dios grande,~soberano de todos los dioses,~tiene en su mano las simas de la tierra,~son suyas las cumbres de los montes. ~Suyo es el mar, porque él lo hizo,~la tierra firme que modelaron sus manos.§Venid, postrémonos por tierra,~bendiciendo al Señor, creador nuestro. ~Porque él es nuestro Dios,~y nosotros su pueblo,~el rebaño que él guía.§Ojalá escuchéis hoy su voz:~«No endurezcáis el corazón como en Meribá, ~como el día de Masá en el desierto:~cuando vuestros padres me pusieron a prueba,~y dudaron de mí, aunque habían visto mis obras.§Durante cuarenta años~aquella generación me repugnó, y dije:~“Es un pueblo de corazón extraviado,~que no reconoce mi camino;~por eso he jurado en mi cólera~que no entrarán en mi descanso.”»§"
            },
            "himno": {
                "texto": "Tú, Señor, que asumiste la existencia,~la lucha y el dolor que el hombre vive,~no dejes sin la luz de tu presencia~la noche de la muerte que lo aflige.§Te rebajaste, Cristo, hasta la muerte,~y una muerte de cruz, por amor nuestro;~así te exaltó el Padre, al acogerte,~sobre todo poder de tierra y cielo.§Para ascender después gloriosamente,~bajaste sepultado a los abismos;~fue el amor del Señor omnipotente~más fuerte que la muerte y su sino.§Primicia de los muertos, tu victoria~es la fe y la esperanza del creyente,~el secreto final de nuestra historia,~abierta a nueva vida para siempre.§Cuando la noche llegue y sea el día~de pasar de este mundo a nuestro Padre,~concédenos la paz y la alegría~de un encuentro feliz que nunca acabe. Amén."
            },
            "salmodia": {
                "tipo":0,
                "salmoCompleto":[
                        {
                            "orden": "1",
                            "antifona": "De tierra me formaste y me revestiste de carne; Señor, Redentor mío, resucítame en el último día.",
                            "ref": "Salmo 39, 2-14. 17-18",
                            "tema": "",
                            "intro": "",
                            "parte": "1",
                            "salmo": "Yo esperaba con ansia al Señor;_él se inclinó y escuchó mi grito;§me levantó de la fosa fatal,_de la charca fangosa;_afianzó mis pies sobre roca,_y aseguró mis pasos;§me puso en la boca un cántico nuevo,_un himno a nuestro Dios._Muchos, al verlo, quedaron sobrecogidos_y confiaron en el Señor.§Dichoso el hombre que ha puesto_su confianza en el Señor,_y no acude a los idólatras,_que se extravían con engaños.§¡Cuántas maravillas has hecho,_Señor, Dios mío,_cuántos planes en favor nuestro!_Nadie se te puede comparar:_intento proclamarlas, decirlas,_pero superan todo número.§Tú no quieres sacrificios ni ofrendas,_y, en cambio, me abriste el oído;_no pides sacrificio expiatorio,_entonces yo digo: «Aquí estoy_-como está escrito en mi libro-_para hacer tu voluntad.»§Dios mío, lo quiero,_y llevo tu ley en las entrañas."
                        },

                        {
                            "orden": "2",
                            "antifona": "Señor, dígnate librarme, date prisa en socorrerme.",
                            "ref": "",
                            "tema": "",
                            "intro": "",
                            "parte": "2",
                            "salmo": "He proclamado tu salvación_ante la gran asamblea;_no he cerrado los labios:_Señor, tú lo sabes.§No me he guardado en el pecho tu defensa,_he proclamado tu fidelidad y tu salvación,_no he negado tu misericordia y tu lealtad_ante la gran asamblea.§Tú, Señor, no me niegues tu clemencia,_que tu misericordia y tu lealtad me guarden siempre,_porque me cercan desgracias sin cuento.§Se me echan encima mis culpas,_y no puedo huir;_son más que los cabellos de mi cabeza,_y me falta el valor.§Señor, dígnate librarme;_Señor, date prisa en socorrerme.§Alégrense y gocen contigo_todos los que te buscan;_digan siempre: «Grande es el Señor»,_los que desean tu salvación._Yo soy pobre y desdichado,_pero el Señor cuida de mí;_tú eres mi auxilio y mi liberación:_Dios mío, no tardes."
                        },

                        {
                            "orden": "3",
                            "antifona": "Mi alma tiene sed del Dios vivo: ¿cuándo entraré a ver el rostro del Señor?",
                            "ref": "Salmo 41",
                            "tema": "",
                            "intro": "",
                            "parte": "",
                            "salmo": "Como busca la cierva_corrientes de agua,_así mi alma te busca_a ti, Dios mío;§tiene sed de Dios,_del Dios vivo:_¿cuándo entraré a ver_el rostro de Dios?§Las lágrimas son mi pan_noche y día,_mientras todo el día me repiten:_«¿Dónde está tu Dios?»§Recuerdo otros tiempos,_y mi alma desfallece de tristeza:_cómo marchaba a la cabeza del grupo,_hacia la casa de Dios,_entre cantos de júbilo y alabanza,_en el bullicio de la fiesta.§¿Por qué te acongojas, alma mía,_por qué te me turbas?_Espera en Dios, que volverás a alabarlo:_«Salud de mi rostro, Dios mío.»§Cuando mi alma se acongoja,_te recuerdo,_desde el Jordán y el Hermón_y el Monte Menor.§Una sima grita a otra sima_con voz de cascadas:_tus torrentes y tus olas_me han arrollado.§De día el Señor_me hará misericordia,_de noche cantaré la alabanza_del Dios de mi vida.§Diré a Dios: Roca mía,_¿por qué me olvidas?_¿Por qué voy andando sombrío,_hostigado por mi enemigo?§Se me rompen los huesos_por las burlas del adversario;_todo el día me preguntan:_«¿Dónde está tu Dios?»§¿Por qué te acongojas, alma mía,_por qué te me turbas?_Espera en Dios, que volverás a alabarlo:_«Salud de mi rostro, Dios mío.»"
                        }]              
                    },
            "oficioLecturas": {

                "responsorio": "",

                "biblica": {
                    "libro": "De la primera carta del apóstol san Pablo a los Corintios",
                    "capitulo": "15",
                    "v_inicial": "12",
                    "v_final": "-34",
                    "tema": "La resurrección de Cristo esperanza de los creyentes",
                    "texto": "<p>Hermanos: Si se anuncia que Cristo ha resucitado de entre los muertos, ¿cómo dicen algunos de entre vosotros que no hay resurrección de muertos? Pues bien: si no hay resurrección de muertos, tampoco Cristo ha resucitado. Pero si Cristo no ha resucitado, vana es nuestra predicación y vana también vuestra fe; más todavía: resultamos unos falsos testigos de Dios, porque hemos dado testimonio contra él, diciendo que ha resucitado a Cristo, a quien no ha resucitado... si es que los muertos no resucitan.</p> <p>Pues si los muertos no resucitan, tampoco Cristo ha resucitado; y, si Cristo no ha resucitado, vuestra fe no tiene sentido, seguís estando en vuestros pecados; de modo que incluso los que murieron en Cristo han perecido. Si hemos puesto nuestra esperanza en Cristo solo en esta vida, somos los más desgraciados de toda la humanidad.</p> <p>Pero Cristo ha resucitado de entre los muertos y es primicia de los que han muerto. Si por un hombre vino la muerte, por un hombre vino la resurrección. Pues lo mismo que en Adán mueren todos, así en Cristo todos serán vivificados. Pero cada uno en su puesto: primero Cristo, como primicia; después todos los que son de Cristo, en su venida; después el final, cuando Cristo entregue el reino a Dios Padre, cuando haya aniquilado todo principado, poder y fuerza. Pues Cristo tiene que reinar hasta que ponga a todos sus enemigos bajo sus pies. El último enemigo en ser destruido será la muerte, porque lo ha sometido todo bajo sus pies. Pero, cuando dice que ha sometido todo, es evidente que queda excluido el que le ha sometido todo. Y, cuando le haya sometido todo, entonces también el mismo Hijo se someterá al que se lo había sometido todo. Así Dios será todo en todos.</p> <p>De otro modo, ¿qué obtendrán los que se bautizan por los muertos? Si es verdad que los muertos no van a resucitar en absoluto, ¿por qué se bautizan entonces por ellos? Y nosotros mismos, ¿por qué nos exponemos continuamente al peligro? Muero diariamente; lo digo, hermanos, por la gloria que tengo por vosotros en Cristo Jesús, nuestro Señor. Y si combatí contra fieras en Éfeso por motivos humanos, ¿de qué me sirve? Si los muertos no resucitan, <i>comamos y bebamos, que mañana moriremos</i>. No os engañéis: «Las malas compañías corrompen las costumbres». Recuperad la debida sobriedad y no pequéis. Pues lo que tienen algunos es ignorancia de Dios: os lo digo para vergüenza vuestra.</p>",
                    "ref": "1 Co 15, 25-26; cf., Ap 20, 13. 14",
                    "responsorio": "Cristo debe reinar hasta que Dios ponga todos sus enemigos bajo sus pies.|El último enemigo aniquilado será la muerte.|Entonces la muerte y el hades devolverán los muertos, y la muerte y el hades serán arrojados al lago de fuego."
                },

                "patristica": {
                    "padre": "Ambrosio",
                    "obra": " Obra",
                    "fuente": "Libro sobre la muerte de su hermano Sátiro. Lib. 2, 40. 41. 46. 47. 132. 133: CSEL 73, 270-274. 323-324",
                    "tema": "Muramos con Cristo, y viviremos con Él",
                    "texto": "<p>Vemos que la muerte es una ganancia, y la vida un sufrimiento. Por esto, dice san Pablo: <em>Para mí la vida es Cristo, y una ganancia el morir</em>. Cristo, a través de la muerte corporal, se nos convierte en espíritu de vida. Por tanto, <em>muramos con él, y viviremos con él</em>.</p> <p>En cierto modo, debemos irnos acostumbrando y disponiendo a morir, por este esfuerzo cotidiano, que consiste en ir separando el alma de las concupiscencias del cuerpo, que es como irla sacando fuera del mismo para colocarla en un lugar elevado, donde no puedan alcanzarla ni pegarse a ella los deseos terrenales, lo cual viene a ser como una imagen de la muerte, que nos evitará el castigo de la muerte. Porque la ley de la carne está en oposición a la ley del espíritu e induce a ésta a la ley del error. ¿Qué remedio hay para esto? ¿Quién me librará de este cuerpo presa de la muerte? Dios, por medio de nuestro Señor Jesucristo, y le doy gracias.</p> <p>Tenemos un médico, sigamos sus remedios. Nuestro remedio es la gracia de Cristo, y el cuerpo presa de la muerte es nuestro propio cuerpo. Por lo tanto, emigremos del cuerpo, para no vivir lejos del Señor; aunque vivimos en el cuerpo, no sigamos las tendencias del cuerpo ni obremos en contra del orden natural, antes busquemos con preferencia los dones de la gracia.</p> <p>¿Qué más diremos? <em>Con la muerte de uno solo fue redimido el mundo</em>. Cristo hubiese podido evitar la muerte, si así lo hubiese querido; mas no la rehuyó como algo inútil, sino que la consideró como el mejor modo de salvarnos. Y, así, su muerte es la vida de todos.</p> <p>Hemos recibido el signo sacramental de su muerte, anunciamos y proclamamos su muerte siempre que nos reunimos para ofrecer la eucaristía; su muerte es una victoria, su muerte es sacramento, su muerte es la máxima solemnidad anual que celebra el mundo.</p> <p>¿Qué más podremos decir de su muerte, si el ejemplo de Cristo nos demuestra que ella sola consiguió la inmortalidad y se redimió a sí misma? Por esto, no debemos deplorar la muerte, ya que es causa de salvación para todos; no debemos rehuirla, puesto que el Hijo de Dios no la rehuyó ni tuvo en menos el sufrirla.</p> <p>Además, la muerte no formaba parte de nuestra naturaleza, sino que se introdujo en ella; Dios no instituyó la muerte desde el principio, sino que nos la dio como un remedio. En efecto, la vida del hombre, condenada, por culpa del pecado, a un duro trabajo y a un sufrimiento intolerable, comenzó a ser digna de lástima: era necesario dar fin a estos males, de modo que la muerte restituyera lo que la vida había perdido. La inmortalidad, en efecto, es más una carga que un bien, si no entra en juego la gracia.</p> <p>Nuestro espíritu aspira a abandonar las sinuosidades de esta vida y los enredos del cuerpo terrenal y llegar a aquella asamblea celestial, a la que sólo llegan los santos, para cantar a Dios aquella alabanza que, como nos dice la Escritura, le cantan al son de la cítara: <em>Grandes y maravillosas son tus obras, Señor, Dios omnipotente, justos y verdaderos tus caminos, ¡oh Rey de los siglos! ¿Quién no temerá, Señor, y glorificará tu nombre? Porque tú solo eres santo, porque vendrán todas las naciones y se postrarán en tu acatamiento</em>; y también para contemplar, Jesús, tu boda mística, cuando la esposa, en medio de la aclamación de todos, será transportada de la tierra al cielo —a ti acude todo mortal—, libre ya de las ataduras de este mundo y unida al espíritu.</p> <p>Este deseo expresaba, con especial vehemencia, el salmista, cuando decía: <em>Una cosa pido al Señor, eso buscaré: habitar en la casa del Señor por los días de mi vida y gozar de la dulzura del Señor</em>.</p>",
                    "ref": "Cf. 2 M 12,45; Mt 13,43",
                    "responsorio": "A los que han muerto piadosamente|les está reservado un magnífico premio.|Entonces los justos brillarán como el sol en el reino de su Padre."
                },
            "teDeum": {
                "status":false,
                "texto":""
            },

                "oracion": "Escucha, Señor, nuestras súplicas~y haz que, al proclamar nuestra fe~en la resurrección de tu Hijo,~se avive también nuestra esperanza~en la resurrección de nuestros hermanos.~Por nuestro Señor Jesucristo, tu Hijo."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Por ejemplo, si quiero acceder a información del objeto `himno` que está dentro del objeto `oficio` el cual a su vez está dentro está dentro de `breviario`, dispongo de las siguientes clases:

#### `Breviario`

```
public class Breviario
{
    public MetaLiturgia metaLiturgia;
    public Santo santo;
    public Oficio oficio;

    public MetaLiturgia getMetaLiturgia() {
        return metaLiturgia;
    }

    public void setMetaLiturgia(MetaLiturgia metaLiturgia) {
        this.metaLiturgia = metaLiturgia;
    }

    public Santo getSanto() {
        return santo;
    }

    public void setSanto(Santo santo) {
        this.santo = santo;
    }

    public Oficio getOficio() {
        return oficio;
    }

    public void setOficio(Oficio oficio) {
        this.oficio = oficio;
    }
}
```

#### `Oficio`

```
public class Oficio
{
    public Invitatorio invitatorio;
    public Himno himno;

    public String responsorio;
    public OficioLecturas oficioLecturas;

    public Invitatorio getInvitatorio() {
        return invitatorio;
    }

    public void setInvitatorio(Invitatorio invitatorio) {
        this.invitatorio = invitatorio;
    }

    public String getResponsorio() {
        return responsorio;
    }

    public void setResponsorio(String responsorio) {
        this.responsorio = responsorio;
    }

    public Himno getHimno() {
        return himno;
    }

    public void setHimno(Himno himno) {
        this.himno = himno;
    }

    public OficioLecturas getOficioLecturas() {
        return oficioLecturas;
    }

    public void setOficioLecturas(OficioLecturas oficioLecturas) {
        this.oficioLecturas = oficioLecturas;
    }


}
```

#### `Himno`

```
public class Himno {
    public String texto;

    public Spanned getTexto() {
        Spanned str= Utils.fromHtml(Utils.getFormato(texto));
        return str;
    }

    public SpannableStringBuilder getHeader() {

        return Utils.formatTitle("HIMNO");
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }
}
```

La forma en que intento acceder es la siguiente:

```
Breviario breviario = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonDatos), Breviario.class);
Oficio oficio=breviario.getOficio();
Himno himno=oficio.getHimno();
Log.d(TAG,himno.getTexto().toString());
```

No me funciona, me da el error siguiente:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'org.deiverbum.app.model.Himno
>   org.deiverbum.app.model.Oficio.getHimno()' on a null object reference
>                         at org.deiverbum.app.activities.OficioActivity.getResponseData(OficioActivity.java:111)

¿Por qué no me funciona, si `getOficio` debería devolver un objeto del tipo `Oficio` y `getHimno` debería devolver un objeto del tipo `Himno`?

¿Cómo debería hacer esto, sabiendo que quiero usar la estructura y organización de mi modelo de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Usa esta herramienta :
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Alli podras generar tus clases rapidamente y con compatibilidad con GSON, creo que lo que no funciona es por que la refleccion no funciona necesitas agregar las anotaciones:

Donde tu clase principal seria MyJSONClass, solo agregar estas clases y sustituir tu parceo por:

```
Breviario breviario = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonDatos), MyJSONClass.class);

public class Biblica {

    @SerializedName("libro")
    @Expose
    private String libro;
    @SerializedName("capitulo")
    @Expose
    private String capitulo;
    @SerializedName("v_inicial")
    @Expose
    private String vInicial;
    @SerializedName("v_final")
    @Expose
    private String vFinal;
    @SerializedName("tema")
    @Expose
    private String tema;
    @SerializedName("texto")
    @Expose
    private String texto;
    @SerializedName("ref")
    @Expose
    private String ref;
    @SerializedName("responsorio")
    @Expose
    private String responsorio;

    public String getLibro() {
        return libro;
    }

    public void setLibro(String libro) {
        this.libro = libro;
    }

    public String getCapitulo() {
        return capitulo;
    }

    public void setCapitulo(String capitulo) {
        this.capitulo = capitulo;
    }

    public String getVInicial() {
        return vInicial;
    }

    public void setVInicial(String vInicial) {
        this.vInicial = vInicial;
    }

    public String getVFinal() {
        return vFinal;
    }

    public void setVFinal(String vFinal) {
        this.vFinal = vFinal;
    }

    public String getTema() {
        return tema;
    }

    public void setTema(String tema) {
        this.tema = tema;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public String getResponsorio() {
        return responsorio;
    }

    public void setResponsorio(String responsorio) {
        this.responsorio = responsorio;
    }

}

public class Breviario {

    @SerializedName("metaLiturgia")
    @Expose
    private MetaLiturgia metaLiturgia;
    @SerializedName("santo")
    @Expose
    private Santo santo;
    @SerializedName("oficio")
    @Expose
    private Oficio oficio;

    public MetaLiturgia getMetaLiturgia() {
        return metaLiturgia;
    }

    public void setMetaLiturgia(MetaLiturgia metaLiturgia) {
        this.metaLiturgia = metaLiturgia;
    }

    public Santo getSanto() {
        return santo;
    }

    public void setSanto(Santo santo) {
        this.santo = santo;
    }

    public Oficio getOficio() {
        return oficio;
    }

    public void setOficio(Oficio oficio) {
        this.oficio = oficio;
    }

}

public class MyJSONClass {

    @SerializedName("breviario")
    @Expose
    private Breviario breviario;

    public Breviario getBreviario() {
        return breviario;
    }

    public void setBreviario(Breviario breviario) {
        this.breviario = breviario;
    }

}

public class Himno {

    @SerializedName("texto")
    @Expose
    private String texto;

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

}

public class Invitatorio {

    @SerializedName("antifona")
    @Expose
    private String antifona;
    @SerializedName("texto")
    @Expose
    private String texto;

    public String getAntifona() {
        return antifona;
    }

    public void setAntifona(String antifona) {
        this.antifona = antifona;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

}

public class MetaLiturgia {

    @SerializedName("fecha")
    @Expose
    private String fecha;
    @SerializedName("tiempo")
    @Expose
    private String tiempo;
    @SerializedName("semana")
    @Expose
    private String semana;
    @SerializedName("mensaje")
    @Expose
    private String mensaje;
    @SerializedName("salterio")
    @Expose
    private String salterio;
    @SerializedName("color")
    @Expose
    private Integer color;
    @SerializedName("meta")
    @Expose
    private String meta;

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getTiempo() {
        return tiempo;
    }

    public void setTiempo(String tiempo) {
        this.tiempo = tiempo;
    }

    public String getSemana() {
        return semana;
    }

    public void setSemana(String semana) {
        this.semana = semana;
    }

    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

    public String getSalterio() {
        return salterio;
    }

    public void setSalterio(String salterio) {
        this.salterio = salterio;
    }

    public Integer getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Integer color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public void setMeta(String meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

}

public class Oficio {

    @SerializedName("invitatorio")
    @Expose
    private Invitatorio invitatorio;
    @SerializedName("himno")
    @Expose
    private Himno himno;
    @SerializedName("salmodia")
    @Expose
    private Salmodia salmodia;
    @SerializedName("oficioLecturas")
    @Expose
    private OficioLecturas oficioLecturas;

    public Invitatorio getInvitatorio() {
        return invitatorio;
    }

    public void setInvitatorio(Invitatorio invitatorio) {
        this.invitatorio = invitatorio;
    }

    public Himno getHimno() {
        return himno;
    }

    public void setHimno(Himno himno) {
        this.himno = himno;
    }

    public Salmodia getSalmodia() {
        return salmodia;
    }

    public void setSalmodia(Salmodia salmodia) {
        this.salmodia = salmodia;
    }

    public OficioLecturas getOficioLecturas() {
        return oficioLecturas;
    }

    public void setOficioLecturas(OficioLecturas oficioLecturas) {
        this.oficioLecturas = oficioLecturas;
    }

}

public class OficioLecturas {

    @SerializedName("responsorio")
    @Expose
    private String responsorio;
    @SerializedName("biblica")
    @Expose
    private Biblica biblica;
    @SerializedName("patristica")
    @Expose
    private Patristica patristica;
    @SerializedName("teDeum")
    @Expose
    private TeDeum teDeum;
    @SerializedName("oracion")
    @Expose
    private String oracion;

    public String getResponsorio() {
        return responsorio;
    }

    public void setResponsorio(String responsorio) {
        this.responsorio = responsorio;
    }

    public Biblica getBiblica() {
        return biblica;
    }

    public void setBiblica(Biblica biblica) {
        this.biblica = biblica;
    }

    public Patristica getPatristica() {
        return patristica;
    }

    public void setPatristica(Patristica patristica) {
        this.patristica = patristica;
    }

    public TeDeum getTeDeum() {
        return teDeum;
    }

    public void setTeDeum(TeDeum teDeum) {
        this.teDeum = teDeum;
    }

    public String getOracion() {
        return oracion;
    }

    public void setOracion(String oracion) {
        this.oracion = oracion;
    }

}

public class Patristica {

    @SerializedName("padre")
    @Expose
    private String padre;
    @SerializedName("obra")
    @Expose
    private String obra;
    @SerializedName("fuente")
    @Expose
    private String fuente;
    @SerializedName("tema")
    @Expose
    private String tema;
    @SerializedName("texto")
    @Expose
    private String texto;
    @SerializedName("ref")
    @Expose
    private String ref;
    @SerializedName("responsorio")
    @Expose
    private String responsorio;

    public String getPadre() {
        return padre;
    }

    public void setPadre(String padre) {
        this.padre = padre;
    }

    public String getObra() {
        return obra;
    }

    public void setObra(String obra) {
        this.obra = obra;
    }

    public String getFuente() {
        return fuente;
    }

    public void setFuente(String fuente) {
        this.fuente = fuente;
    }

    public String getTema() {
        return tema;
    }

    public void setTema(String tema) {
        this.tema = tema;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public String getResponsorio() {
        return responsorio;
    }

    public void setResponsorio(String responsorio) {
        this.responsorio = responsorio;
    }

}

public class SalmoCompleto {

    @SerializedName("orden")
    @Expose
    private String orden;
    @SerializedName("antifona")
    @Expose
    private String antifona;
    @SerializedName("ref")
    @Expose
    private String ref;
    @SerializedName("tema")
    @Expose
    private String tema;
    @SerializedName("intro")
    @Expose
    private String intro;
    @SerializedName("parte")
    @Expose
    private String parte;
    @SerializedName("salmo")
    @Expose
    private String salmo;

    public String getOrden() {
        return orden;
    }

    public void setOrden(String orden) {
        this.orden = orden;
    }

    public String getAntifona() {
        return antifona;
    }

    public void setAntifona(String antifona) {
        this.antifona = antifona;
    }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public String getTema() {
        return tema;
    }

    public void setTema(String tema) {
        this.tema = tema;
    }

    public String getIntro() {
        return intro;
    }

    public void setIntro(String intro) {
        this.intro = intro;
    }

    public String getParte() {
        return parte;
    }

    public void setParte(String parte) {
        this.parte = parte;
    }

    public String getSalmo() {
        return salmo;
    }

    public void setSalmo(String salmo) {
        this.salmo = salmo;
    }

}

public class Salmodia {

    @SerializedName("tipo")
    @Expose
    private Integer tipo;
    @SerializedName("salmoCompleto")
    @Expose
    private List<SalmoCompleto> salmoCompleto = null;

    public Integer getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(Integer tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public List<SalmoCompleto> getSalmoCompleto() {
        return salmoCompleto;
    }

    public void setSalmoCompleto(List<SalmoCompleto> salmoCompleto) {
        this.salmoCompleto = salmoCompleto;
    }

}

public class Santo {

    @SerializedName("nombre")
    @Expose
    private String nombre;
    @SerializedName("vida")
    @Expose
    private String vida;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getVida() {
        return vida;
    }

    public void setVida(String vida) {
        this.vida = vida;
    }

}

public class TeDeum {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Boolean status;
    @SerializedName("texto")
    @Expose
    private String texto;

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Yo use la herramienta [`jsonutils.com`](https://jsonutils.com) para crear mis clases. ¿Sabes por qué habría que serializarlo todo? ¿Eso no interferirá si quiero usar mis clases también con otro código como `Firebase`  o para mapear resultados obtenidos de la bases de datos?

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciones @JoseAlbertoNavarroBarrios pero te recomiendo revisar [answer] para realizar respuestas a las preguntas del sitio y estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: No afecta @A.Cedano, Y creo que mas que la serializacion es porque el json que estas recibiendo no es compatible con tus clases dado que es un JSON que contiene un nodo "brevario" y tu le estas pasando directamente a la clase Brevario lo que necesitas es crear otra clase que contenga una variable de tipo Brevario, no se si me explique.

Comment: Checa de las clases que puse MyJSONClass, esa clase es la que te falta, la serializacion se realiza cuando haces ofuscado de codigo y por tanto la reflexion deja de funcionar.

Comment: José creé las clases con la herramienta que me indicas en el enlace, con las anotaciones propias de Gson, pero aún así no me funciona. Tuve que ponerlo así: `JSONObject jsonBreviario = jsonDatos.getJSONObject("breviario");
            Breviario breviario = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonBreviario), Breviario.class);` y ahí si funciona, no sé por qué, pero parece que primero hay que crear un `JSONObject` con la 1ª clave del objeto y a partir de ahí crear la referencia a la clase `Breviario`. En mi lógica Gson debería asumir que si la 1ª llave es `breviario` se puede mapear...

Comment: ... todo el objeto a esa clase, la cual refleja cada propiedad para cada elemento del JSON, pero no lo hace así y no entiendo por qué tengo que sacar aparte de esta forma la primera clave: `JSONObject jsonBreviario = jsonDatos.getJSONObject("breviario");` Mi objeto es `JSONObject` (recibido vía `Volley`). Tampoco entiendo por qué si Gson es para trabajar con JSON, me obliga (aparentemente) a cambiarlo a `String`. Para mi eso no tiene ningún sentido ¿por qué no lo mapea como JSON, ese no es el objetivo de esa librería?. @Jorgesys ¿tú sabes algo de esto?